# Telegram Bot API sendPhoto url contains characters like right single quotation mark (’)

Tags: url, telegram-bot, sendmessage

I am using standard Telegram Bot API for sending messages. When a photo url contains a special character like a right single quotation mark (’) and left single quote (‘), the message is not sent, as it is a Bad Request.
When php `rawurlencode` is run, `’` shows as `%E2%80%99` and `‘` as `%E2%80%98`

```
$photourl='https://example.com/some/path/name-of-image-with‘quotes’.jpg';
$array =[
'chat_id' => $uid,
'photo' => $photourl,
'caption' => $caption
];
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$api/sendPhoto?".http_build_query($array) );
```

it gives a

> PHP WARNING --
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$photourl = 'https://example.com/some/path/name-of-image-with‘quotes’.jpg';
$filename = basename($photourl);
$photourl = str_replace($filename, urlencode($filename), $photourl); //Replace file name wirth url encoded filename

$array = [
    'chat_id' => $uid,
    'photo' => $photourl,
    'caption' => $caption
];
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$api/sendPhoto?" . http_build_query($array));
```

Using characters like `’`,`‘` or `*` in `photo` parameter seem to cause a problem.

I don't have any explanation why this error occurs or how this fixes it. But you can url encode the URL's file name part before passing your query to `http_build_query()`, (which will  encode it even a second time).

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. I'll test it out thoroughly.